# no estoy recibiendo el valor de un select angular 9

Tags: angular9

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]//tengo el siguiente select en angular

```
<select [(ngModel)]="user.sexo" name="sexo">
   <option value="hombre" selected>Hombre</option>
   <option value="mujer">Mujer</option>
   <option value="indefinido">Prefiero no decirlo</option>
</select>
```

//aqui esta el component.ts para recibir los datos, recivo todos los datos perfectamente pero los del select no, cual seria el problema aca?

```
user = {
  nombre: "",
  apellido: "",
  username: "",
  email: "", //aqui creo las variables para guardar los datos que traigo del html
  birth: "",
  sexo: "",
  password: "",
  confirmPassword: "",
};

register(e) {
  console.log(this.user);

  if (this.user.nombre.length < 2) {
    return false;
  } else if (this.user.apellido.length < 2) {
    return false;
  } else if (this.user.username.length <= 4) {
    return false;
  } else if (this.user.email.length < 8) {
    //aqui deberia ir los componentes que le avisan al usuario el error que cometieron
    return false;
  } else if (this.user.sexo == "") {
    return false;
  } else if (this.user.password.length < 8) {
    return false;
  } else if (this.user.password != this.user.confirmPassword) {
    return false;
  } else {
    this.autService.register(this.user).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        localStorage.setItem("token", res.token);
        this.route.navigate(["inicio"]);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err.error);
      }
    );
  }
};
```

estoy empezando con angular y no se cual podria ser el error aqui, les agradeceria mucho si me ayuda, buenas noches.

Comment: puedes poner lo que sale en el `console.log(this.user)`. Aquí tienes un error te falta un igual debería ser `this.user.sexo == ''`

Comment: ya lo modifico y subo lo que me devuelve el `console.log(this.user)`

Comment: modificando el error que tenias del igual no te va?

Comment: no, sigo obteniendo un string vacio

Comment: a mi me funciona correctamente quizás el problema esta en otro sitio. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ppen5. Actualiza el error en tu pregunta que he comentado para no crear confusión a otras personas de SO.

Comment: mi solucion fue quitar la variable `sexo` del objeto `user`, no se po que pero eso era lo que no me dejaba obtener el valor del select

Comment: es raro la verdad

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de ngModel para obtener el valor seleccionado.

```
<select name="sexo" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
    <option *ngFor="let item of listOptions" [ngValue]="item" >
    {{item.name}}</option>
</select>

<pre>{{ this.selectedOption | json}}</pre>
```

Código Ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
    listOptions = [
    {
        id:0,
        name:'Hombre'
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:'Mujer'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'Prefiero no decirlo'
    },
]

selectedOption = this.listOptions[0];

}
```

Dejo un ejemplo en stackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcbank

Answer (score 0):

si usas [(ngFmodel)] tienes que usar [ngValue] en los options del select.

Te adjunto un ejemplo en [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-0-0-select-ngmodel?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

No obstante, te recomiendo que te leas la sección [Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) del manual de angular para tener un mejor control de los formularios y que de cara a validaciones y demás te resulte más fácil

Comment: El ejemplo debería ir aquí amigo así se preserva la información

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que estoy viendo en tu ngmodel necesitas añadir una variable a la etiqueta y te deberia quedar algo asi:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="user.sexo" name="sexo" #sexo="ngModel">
   <option value="hombre" selected>Hombre</option>
   <option value="mujer">Mujer</option>
   <option value="indefinido">Prefiero no decirlo</option>
</select>
```

Por si no te percatas del cambio ya que es muy sutil, simplemente he añadido #sexo="ngModel"